# php error. Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection.php on line 15

Error i am a begginer kinda on website making but pro on visual studio programming please tell me whats wrong here. The code:

http://pastebin.com/bE1dXARC

Learning coding from youtube. If this is suspicious. Link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w428f-ByczE&src_vid=YkzD5lYUsEs&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_169240 please help.

Comment: There is a semicolon (`;`) missing to end the statement the line before

Comment: A pro at VS should be able to find a syntax error like this with a bit of effort.

Comment: Also I would suggest finding another tutorial. `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will (likely) be removed in the future. Switch to [PDO or MySQLi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) and learn it right from the start

Comment: As above, various missing semicolons. And if you are used to visual studio, then you would be right at home using a decent php ide (phpstorm - paid, netbeans - free) that would pick up errors like this. Lastly that tutorial stinks.

Comment: Why did you add the `@` before `mysql_select_db`? It surpresses errors that might contain useful information. -edit- Steve is right, that tutorial stinks. It contains nothing but bad practises and outdated functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolon is missing in the lines where you are echoing the queries. You have to end PHP line of code with a semicolon.

```
@mysql_select_db($website_information) or ("Database error number 1");

echo $query;
echo $querypass;
echo $queryemail;
```

Comment: And those are not the only ones. The line with `mysql_select_db` is also missing a `;`.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I will search for other tutorials and learn php and html coding.

Answer (score 0):

No semi-colon on line 13

```
@mysql_select_db($website_information) or ("Database error number 1") and

echo $query
echo $querypass
echo $queryemail 

as mentioned by @Jenz
```

Comment: I really dont get it, Whats the use of this answer ? Do not duplicate the existing answers

Answer (score 0):

There was no die() after @mysql_select_db, added that. No semicolons after line 13, 19, 20, 21, added them too.

```
<?php
$inputuser = $_POST["usernamelogin"];
$inputpass = $_POST["passlogin"];
$inputemail = $_POST["emaillogin"];
$usernamelogin = "";
$passlogin = "";
$emaillogin = "";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost",$usernamelogin,$passlogin,$emaillogin);
@mysql_select_db($website_information) or die("Database error number 1");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `critical_account_information` WHERE `usernamelogin` = '$inputuser'";
$querypass = "SELECT * FROM `critical_account_information` WHERE `passlogin` = '$inputpass'";
$queryemail = "SELECT * FROM `critical_account_information` WHERE `emaillogin` = '$inputemail'";

echo $query;
echo $querypass;
echo $queryemail;

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: excuse me, see before commenting, only my answer has 

`@mysql_select_db($website_information) or die("Database error number 1");`

All other answers have -

`@mysql_select_db($website_information) or ("Database error number 1")`

Comment: And this what happens when you just write a block of code without any explanation or information. Anyway Good,it is worth mentioning . Please add some line before code justifying how you code is different and efficient than others

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. :) I added a bit on information of the code.

Answer (score -3):

You cann't put the query results directly in a variable. You need to use mysql_query() php function for the query and mysql_fetch_array() to get the results...

See this links:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php